# How to hide a tab in QTabWidget and show it when a button is pressed

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have already created the tabs in QtabWidget. My main purpose is to hide tabs and show it when a button is pressed. I don't want to remove and add tabs every time. I want to hide it and show when required.

I have tried to do this:

```
self.tab.hide()
```

But this doesn't work.
Here is the code for current GUI:

```
    MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
    MainWindow.resize(680, 425)
    self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
    self.verticalLayout_3 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
    self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_3"))
    self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.tabWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tabWidget"))
    self.tab = QtGui.QWidget()
    self.tab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab"))
    self.verticalLayout_4 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.tab)
    self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_4"))
    self.pushButton_3 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.tab)
    self.pushButton_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_3"))
    self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
    self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, _fromUtf8(""))
    self.tab_2 = QtGui.QWidget()
    self.tab_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab_2"))
    self.verticalLayout_5 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.tab_2)
    self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_5"))
    self.treeWidget = QtGui.QTreeWidget(self.tab_2)
    self.treeWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("treeWidget"))
    self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.treeWidget)
    self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, _fromUtf8(""))
    self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 680, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
    self.dockWidget = QtGui.QDockWidget(MainWindow)
    self.dockWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dockWidget"))
    self.dockWidgetContents = QtGui.QWidget()
    self.dockWidgetContents.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dockWidgetContents"))
    self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.dockWidgetContents)
    self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
    self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.dockWidgetContents)
    self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
    self.dockWidget.setWidget(self.dockWidgetContents)
    MainWindow.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.DockWidgetArea(1), self.dockWidget)
    self.dockWidget_2 = QtGui.QDockWidget(MainWindow)
    self.dockWidget_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dockWidget_2"))
    self.dockWidgetContents_2 = QtGui.QWidget()
    self.dockWidgetContents_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dockWidgetContents_2"))
    self.verticalLayout_2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.dockWidgetContents_2)
    self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_2"))
    self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.dockWidgetContents_2)
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
    self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
    self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.dockWidgetContents_2)
    self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
    self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
    self.dockWidget_2.setWidget(self.dockWidgetContents_2)
    MainWindow.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.DockWidgetArea(1), self.dockWidget_2)
```

Answer (score 21):

There is no convenient method to hide a tab. You have two workarounds:

1. Use `removeTab` and `insertTab`. You need to keep a reference to the tabs that you removed to be able to re-insert them later (and their indexes, so that they reappear on the same spot).
2. Use `setTabEnabled` to enable (=show) and disabled (=hide) tabs. When a tab is disabled, it's usually grayed out, but you can use style sheets to hide the tab instead:

   ```
   self.setTabEnabled(tabIndex,True/False) #enable/disable the tab
   # set the style sheet
   self.setStyleSheet("QTabBar::tab::disabled {width: 0; height: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none;} ")
   ```

I tested the second option, and had an issue when showing a previously hidden tab: the view was not repainted properly (even after calling `update` or `repaint`). Turns out the style sheet is not automatically updated and it still draws the tab as if it was disabled.
Calling `setStyleSheet` after every `setTabEnabled(index,True)` fixes the issue. It forces the style sheet to be recompute.

Comment: I tested this before, and instead of setting the StyleSheet every time, you can set it once, and then reapply it every time using polish/unpolish. eg. something like `self.style()->unpolish(self)`; then `self-style()->polish(self);`

Comment: or you can set it in Qt Designer.

Comment: This applies to QT before 5.15, in QT 5.15 and above there is direct support (see user13672091's answer for details).

Answer (score 15):

Since PyQT version 5.15 you can use [`setTabVisible(index, visible)`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QTabWidget.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QTabWidget.setTabVisible). It will hide the tab at given index. When you will pass visible as true, it will show that tab and index will remain the same.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#:~:text=void%20QTabWidget%3A%3AsetTabVisible(int%20index%2C%20bool%20visible)